# Kafka Streams - adding message frequency in enriched stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

From a stream  (k,v),  I want to calculate a stream (k, (v,f)) where f is the frequency of the occurrences of a given key in the last n seconds.
Give a topic (t1) if I use a windowed table to calculate the frequency:

```
KTable<Windowed<Integer>,Long> t1_velocity_table = t1_stream.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(n*1000)).count();
```

This will give a windowed table with the frequency of each key.

Assuming I won’t be able to join with a Windowed key, instead of the table above I am mapping the stream to a table with simple key:

```
t1_Stream.groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of( n*1000)).count()
                .toStream().map((k,v)->new KeyValue<>(k.key(), Math.toIntExact(v))).to(frequency_topic);
KTable<Integer,Integer> t1_frequency_table = builder.table(frequency_topic);
```

If I now lookup in this table when a new key arrives in my stream, how do I know if this lookup table will be updated first or the join will occur first (which will cause the stale frequency to be added in the record rather that the current updated one). Will it be better to create a stream instead of table and then do a windowed join ?
I want to lookup the table with something like this:

```
KStream<Integer,Tuple<Integer,Integer>> t1_enriched = t1_Stream.join(t1_frequency_table, (l,r) -> new Tuple<>(l, r));
```

So instead of having just a stream of (k,v) I have a stream of (k,(v,f)) where f is the frequency of key k in the last n seconds.

Any thoughts on what would be the right way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow. What join are you talking about? Also note, that by stripping the windowed key down to the plain key, you will get incorrect results if your input streams contains out-of-order data...

Comment: Thanks Matthias, updated with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the particular program you shared, the stream side record will be processed first. The reason is, that you pipe the data through a topic...

When the record is processed, it will update the aggregation result that will emit an update record that is written to the through-topic. Directly afterwards, the record will be processed by the join operator. Only afterwards a new `poll()` call will eventually read the aggregation result from the through-topic and update the table side of the join.

Using the DSL, it seems not to be possible for achieve what you want. However, you can write a custom `Transformer` that re-implements the stream-table join that provides the semantics you need.